# Tensorflow InvalidArgumentError: ConcatOp : Dimensions of inputs should match: hape[0] = [32,64] vs. shape[1] = [1,1]

Tags: python, tensorflow

Could someone please help me on this error message? I dont understand why dimensionality is failing. Im thinking I have to save my data to tf structure, but I wouldnt know how. Its failing at the `model.fit` line

```
InvalidArgumentError:  ConcatOp : Dimensions of inputs should match: shape[0] = [32,64] vs. shape[1] = [1,1]
     [[node functional_15/tf_op_layer_concat_1/concat_1 (defined at <ipython-input-111-a47d0926c8a7>:28) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_1236905]
```

### This is how I built my network:

```
Model: "functional_1"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_2 (InputLayer)            [(None, 10, 1)]      0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
lstm (LSTM)                     (None, 64)           16896       input_2[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
input_1 (InputLayer)            [(None, 1)]          0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate (Concatenate)       (None, 65)           0           lstm[0][0]                       
                                                                 input_1[0][0]                    
==================================================================================================
Total params: 16,896
Trainable params: 16,896
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
None
Model: "functional_3"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_4 (InputLayer)            [(None, 10, 1)]      0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
lstm_1 (LSTM)                   (None, 64)           16896       input_4[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
input_3 (InputLayer)            [(None, 1)]          0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_1 (Concatenate)     (None, 65)           0           lstm_1[0][0]                     
                                                                 input_3[0][0]                    
==================================================================================================
Total params: 16,896
Trainable params: 16,896
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
None
Model: "functional_5"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_6 (InputLayer)            [(None, 10, 1)]      0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
lstm_2 (LSTM)                   (None, 64)           16896       input_6[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
input_5 (InputLayer)            [(None, 1)]          0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_2 (Concatenate)     (None, 65)           0           lstm_2[0][0]                     
                                                                 input_5[0][0]                    
==================================================================================================
Total params: 16,896
Trainable params: 16,896
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
None
Model: "functional_7"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_8 (InputLayer)            [(None, 10, 1)]      0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
lstm_3 (LSTM)                   (None, 64)           16896       input_8[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
input_7 (InputLayer)            [(None, 1)]          0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_3 (Concatenate)     (None, 65)           0           lstm_3[0][0]                     
                                                                 input_7[0][0]                    
==================================================================================================
Total params: 16,896
Trainable params: 16,896
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
None
Model: "functional_9"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_10 (InputLayer)           [(None, 10, 1)]      0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
lstm_4 (LSTM)                   (None, 64)           16896       input_10[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
input_9 (InputLayer)            [(None, 1)]          0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_4 (Concatenate)     (None, 65)           0           lstm_4[0][0]                     
                                                                 input_9[0][0]                    
==================================================================================================
Total params: 16,896
Trainable params: 16,896
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
None
Model: "functional_11"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_12 (InputLayer)           [(None, 10, 1)]      0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
lstm_5 (LSTM)                   (None, 64)           16896       input_12[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
input_11 (InputLayer)           [(None, 1)]          0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_5 (Concatenate)     (None, 65)           0           lstm_5[0][0]                     
                                                                 input_11[0][0]                   
==================================================================================================
Total params: 16,896
Trainable params: 16,896
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
None
Model: "functional_13"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_14 (InputLayer)           [(None, 10, 1)]      0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
lstm_6 (LSTM)                   (None, 64)           16896       input_14[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
input_13 (InputLayer)           [(None, 1)]          0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_6 (Concatenate)     (None, 65)           0           lstm_6[0][0]                     
                                                                 input_13[0][0]                   
==================================================================================================
Total params: 16,896
Trainable params: 16,896
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
None
model shape:  (None, 10, 1)
output 2:  Tensor("concat:0", shape=(1, 65), dtype=float32)
model shape:  (None, 10, 1)
output 2:  Tensor("concat_1:0", shape=(1, 65), dtype=float32)
model shape:  (None, 10, 1)
output 2:  Tensor("concat_2:0", shape=(1, 65), dtype=float32)
model shape:  (None, 10, 1)
output 2:  Tensor("concat_3:0", shape=(1, 65), dtype=float32)
model shape:  (None, 10, 1)
output 2:  Tensor("concat_4:0", shape=(1, 65), dtype=float32)
model shape:  (None, 10, 1)
output 2:  Tensor("concat_5:0", shape=(1, 65), dtype=float32)
model shape:  (None, 10, 1)
output 2:  Tensor("concat_6:0", shape=(1, 65), dtype=float32)
output penul:  Tensor("dense/Relu:0", shape=(1, 30), dtype=float32)
output:  Tensor("dense_1/BiasAdd:0", shape=(1, 1), dtype=float32)
Modelo completo
Model: "functional_15"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
Input1 (InputLayer)             [(None, 10, 7)]      0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
tf_op_layer_strided_slice (Tens [(None, 10, 1)]      0           Input1[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
tf_op_layer_strided_slice_1 (Te [(None, 10, 1)]      0           Input1[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
tf_op_layer_lstm/Shape_1 (Tenso [(3,)]               0           tf_op_layer_strided_slice[0][0]  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
tf_op_layer_lstm_1/Shape_1 (Ten [(3,)]               0           tf_op_layer_strided_slice_1[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
tf_op_layer_strided_slice_2 (Te [(None, 10, 1)]      0           Input1[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
tf_op_layer_lstm/strided_slice_ [()]                 0           tf_op_layer_lstm/Shape_1[0][0]   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
tf_op_layer_lstm_1/strided_slic [()]                 0           tf_op_layer_lstm_1/Shape_1[0][0] 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
tf_op_layer_lstm_2/Shape_1 (Ten [(3,)]               0           tf_op_layer_strided_slice_2[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
tf_op_layer_strided_slice_3 (Te [(None, 10, 1)]      0           Input1[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
tf_op_layer_lstm/zeros_2/packed [(2,)]               0           tf_op_layer_lstm/strided_slice_1[
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
tf_op_layer_lstm/zeros_3/packed [(2,)]               0           tf_op_layer_lstm/strided_slice_1[
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
tf_op_layer_lstm_1/zeros_2/pack [(2,)]               0           tf_op_layer_lstm_1/strided_slice_
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
tf_op_layer_lstm_1/zeros_3/pack [(2,)]               0           tf_op_layer_lstm_1/strided_slice_
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
tf_op_layer_lstm_2/strided_slic [()]                 0           tf_op_layer_lstm_2/Shape_1[0][0] 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
tf_op_layer_lstm_3/Shape_1 (Ten [(3,)]               0           tf_op_layer_strided_slice_3[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
tf_op_layer_strided_slice_4 (Te [(None, 10, 1)]      0           Input1[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
tf_op_layer_lstm/zeros_2 (Tenso [(None, 64)]         0           tf_op_layer_lstm/zeros_2/packed[0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
tf_op_layer_lstm/zeros_3 (Tenso [(None, 64)]         0           tf_op_layer_lstm/zeros_3/packed[0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
tf_op_layer_lstm_1/zeros_2 (Ten [(None, 64)]         0           tf_op_layer_lstm_1/zeros_2/packed
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
tf_op_layer_lstm_1/zeros_3 (Ten [(None, 64)]         0           tf_op_layer_lstm_1/zeros_3/packed
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
tf_op_layer_lstm_2/zeros_2/pack [(2,)]               0           tf_op_layer_lstm_2/strided_slice_
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
tf_op_layer_lstm_2/zeros_3/pack [(2,)]               0           tf_op_layer_lstm_2/strided_slice_
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
tf_op_layer_lstm_3/strided_slic [()]                 0           tf_op_layer_lstm_3/Shape_1[0][0] 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
tf_op_layer_lstm_4/Shape_1 (Ten [(3,)]               0           tf_op_layer_strided_slice_4[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
tf_op_layer_strided_slice_5 (Te [(None, 10, 1)]      0           Input1[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
tf_op_layer_lstm/PartitionedCal [(None, 64), (None,  0           tf_op_layer_strided_slice[0][0]  
                                                                 tf_op_layer_lstm/zeros_2[0][0]   
                                                                 tf_op_layer_lstm/zeros_3[0][0]   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
tf_op_layer_lstm_1/PartitionedC [(None, 64), (None,  0           tf_op_layer_strided_slice_1[0][0]
                                                                 tf_op_layer_lstm_1/zeros_2[0][0] 
                                                                 tf_op_layer_lstm_1/zeros_3[0][0] 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
tf_op_layer_lstm_2/zeros_2 (Ten [(None, 64)]         0           tf_op_layer_lstm_2/zeros_2/packed
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
tf_op_layer_lstm_2/zeros_3 (Ten [(None, 64)]         0           tf_op_layer_lstm_2/zeros_3/packed
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
tf_op_layer_lstm_3/zeros_2/pack [(2,)]               0           tf_op_layer_lstm_3/strided_slice_
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
tf_op_layer_lstm_3/zeros_3/pack [(2,)]               0           tf_op_layer_lstm_3/strided_slice_
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
tf_op_layer_lstm_4/strided_slic [()]                 0           tf_op_layer_lstm_4/Shape_1[0][0] 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
tf_op_layer_lstm_5/Shape_1 (Ten [(3,)]               0           tf_op_layer_strided_slice_5[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
tf_op_layer_strided_slice_6 (Te [(None, 10, 1)]      0           Input1[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
tf_op_layer_concat (TensorFlowO [(1, 65)]            0           tf_op_layer_lstm/PartitionedCall_
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
tf_op_layer_concat_1 (TensorFlo [(1, 65)]            0           tf_op_layer_lstm_1/PartitionedCal
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
tf_op_layer_lstm_2/PartitionedC [(None, 64), (None,  0           tf_op_layer_strided_slice_2[0][0]
                                                                 tf_op_layer_lstm_2/zeros_2[0][0] 
                                                                 tf_op_layer_lstm_2/zeros_3[0][0] 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
tf_op_layer_lstm_3/zeros_2 (Ten [(None, 64)]         0           tf_op_layer_lstm_3/zeros_2/packed
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
tf_op_layer_lstm_3/zeros_3 (Ten [(None, 64)]         0           tf_op_layer_lstm_3/zeros_3/packed
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
tf_op_layer_lstm_4/zeros_2/pack [(2,)]               0           tf_op_layer_lstm_4/strided_slice_
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
tf_op_layer_lstm_4/zeros_3/pack [(2,)]               0           tf_op_layer_lstm_4/strided_slice_
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
tf_op_layer_lstm_5/strided_slic [()]                 0           tf_op_layer_lstm_5/Shape_1[0][0] 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
tf_op_layer_lstm_6/Shape_1 (Ten [(3,)]               0           tf_op_layer_strided_slice_6[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
add (Add)                       (1, 65)              0           tf_op_layer_concat[0][0]         
                                                                 tf_op_layer_concat_1[0][0]       
                                                                 add[6][0]                        
                                                                 tf_op_layer_concat_2[0][0]       
                                                                 add[7][0]                        
                                                                 tf_op_layer_concat_3[0][0]       
                                                                 add[8][0]                        
                                                                 tf_op_layer_concat_4[0][0]       
                                                                 add[9][0]                        
                                                                 tf_op_layer_concat_5[0][0]       
                                                                 add[10][0]                       
                                                                 tf_op_layer_concat_6[0][0]       
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
tf_op_layer_concat_2 (TensorFlo [(1, 65)]            0           tf_op_layer_lstm_2/PartitionedCal
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
tf_op_layer_lstm_3/PartitionedC [(None, 64), (None,  0           tf_op_layer_strided_slice_3[0][0]
                                                                 tf_op_layer_lstm_3/zeros_2[0][0] 
                                                                 tf_op_layer_lstm_3/zeros_3[0][0] 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
tf_op_layer_lstm_4/zeros_2 (Ten [(None, 64)]         0           tf_op_layer_lstm_4/zeros_2/packed
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
tf_op_layer_lstm_4/zeros_3 (Ten [(None, 64)]         0           tf_op_layer_lstm_4/zeros_3/packed
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
tf_op_layer_lstm_5/zeros_2/pack [(2,)]               0           tf_op_layer_lstm_5/strided_slice_
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
tf_op_layer_lstm_5/zeros_3/pack [(2,)]               0           tf_op_layer_lstm_5/strided_slice_
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
tf_op_layer_lstm_6/strided_slic [()]                 0           tf_op_layer_lstm_6/Shape_1[0][0] 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
tf_op_layer_concat_3 (TensorFlo [(1, 65)]            0           tf_op_layer_lstm_3/PartitionedCal
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
tf_op_layer_lstm_4/PartitionedC [(None, 64), (None,  0           tf_op_layer_strided_slice_4[0][0]
                                                                 tf_op_layer_lstm_4/zeros_2[0][0] 
                                                                 tf_op_layer_lstm_4/zeros_3[0][0] 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
tf_op_layer_lstm_5/zeros_2 (Ten [(None, 64)]         0           tf_op_layer_lstm_5/zeros_2/packed
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
tf_op_layer_lstm_5/zeros_3 (Ten [(None, 64)]         0           tf_op_layer_lstm_5/zeros_3/packed
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
tf_op_layer_lstm_6/zeros_2/pack [(2,)]               0           tf_op_layer_lstm_6/strided_slice_
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
tf_op_layer_lstm_6/zeros_3/pack [(2,)]               0           tf_op_layer_lstm_6/strided_slice_
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
tf_op_layer_concat_4 (TensorFlo [(1, 65)]            0           tf_op_layer_lstm_4/PartitionedCal
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
tf_op_layer_lstm_5/PartitionedC [(None, 64), (None,  0           tf_op_layer_strided_slice_5[0][0]
                                                                 tf_op_layer_lstm_5/zeros_2[0][0] 
                                                                 tf_op_layer_lstm_5/zeros_3[0][0] 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
tf_op_layer_lstm_6/zeros_2 (Ten [(None, 64)]         0           tf_op_layer_lstm_6/zeros_2/packed
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
tf_op_layer_lstm_6/zeros_3 (Ten [(None, 64)]         0           tf_op_layer_lstm_6/zeros_3/packed
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
tf_op_layer_concat_5 (TensorFlo [(1, 65)]            0           tf_op_layer_lstm_5/PartitionedCal
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
tf_op_layer_lstm_6/PartitionedC [(None, 64), (None,  0           tf_op_layer_strided_slice_6[0][0]
                                                                 tf_op_layer_lstm_6/zeros_2[0][0] 
                                                                 tf_op_layer_lstm_6/zeros_3[0][0] 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
tf_op_layer_concat_6 (TensorFlo [(1, 65)]            0           tf_op_layer_lstm_6/PartitionedCal
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                   (1, 30)              1980        add[11][0]                       
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)                 (1, 1)               31          dense[0][0]                      
==================================================================================================
Total params: 2,011
Trainable params: 2,011
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
None
```

### And im calling the train function which is this one:

```
MAX_EPOCHS = 10
def compile_and_fit_varios(model, window_dic, patience=2):
  early_stopping = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss',
                                                    patience=patience,
                                                    mode='min')

  model.compile(loss=tf.losses.MeanSquaredError(), optimizer=tf.optimizers.Adam(),
                metrics=[tf.metrics.MeanAbsoluteError(), tf.keras.metrics.MeanAbsolutePercentageError(), tf.keras.metrics.MeanSquaredLogarithmicError(), tf.keras.metrics.MeanSquaredError(),coeff_determination])

  history = model.fit(
                      x=dataset_X_prueba[0],
                      y=dataset_Y_prueba[0],
                      epochs=MAX_EPOCHS)
     

  return history
```

### Which I call over this input and labels arrays:

```
dataset_X_prueba[0].shape
>> (32, 10, 7, 1)

dataset_Y_prueba[0].shape
>> (32, 10, 7, 1)
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49992806/14290244) helps.